# How do I get a US visa while on a student visa in Canada?

Tags: visas, usa, indian-citizens, canada

I am from India and have come to Canada on student visa. I intend to go to USA for my friend's wedding in the month of September. How do I start with my visa procedure?

Comment: Your question is tagged [tag:bookings] and [tag:airlines] yet you're asking about visas. Is there more to this?

Comment: This question shows a lack of basic self research.

Answer (score 4):

You start by applying online for a non-immigrant visa here:
https://ceac.state.gov/genniv/

Comment: Whoever put the notice on this answer: it's a short answer but it rather completely answers this short question.